# ROS 2 Crystal : Can't get parameter list of string from YAML file

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using ROS 2 Crystal and I'm trying to get a list of string from a YAML file in Python.
The problem is that my list also contains numbers, I don't mind them being converted into strings so my YAML file looks like:

```
some_node:
    ros__parameters:
        some_list: ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'some_string']
```

But the parser keeps converting the strings '1', '2', etc into numbers so I get an error `Failed to parse yaml params file ...: Sequence should be of same type. Value type 'string' do not belong at line_num X`.

If I change `some_string` to an int, I do get an `ARRAY_INTEGER` but that's not what I want.
Any way to force the YAML parser to keep `'1'` as a string ?

I tried using double quotes `"1"`, I tried adding `!!str` or `!!string` but it seems to be ignored and gives the same result.

As a temporary solution, I escape my list with a `:` and remove it in the code but it's a bit ugly...

```
some_node:
    ros__parameters:
        some_list: [':1', ':2', ':3', ':4', ':some_string']
```

Thanks.

edit: Same problem in ROS 2 Dashing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325288/ros-2-crystal-:-can%27t-get-parameter-list-of-string-from-yaml-file/) by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2019-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-06-18**:
This sounds like a bug in the YAML parser. If a value is quoted I think it should be interpreted as a string, not a number. You can open an issue at https://github.com/ros2/rcl

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2019-06-19**:
ok, I opened an issue: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like the issue as been fixed: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/461.

---

Originally posted by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) with karma: 203 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2